# Issues saving current record from custom dialog

Tags: scripting, jython, maximo

I am currently developing a custom app in Maximo Asset Management where i have form and an empty DataTable that have a button, when user clicks this button, a custom dialog appears and user can select a related record from this dialog on a data table to process it by clicking a button to launch an action script. The problem i am facing is when system finish process the record, it saves correctly, but application shows the first record of table and not the current saved record, so user gets confused when this happens.

Let me put an example, lets suppose the first record id of my custom table is CC1055 and the current saved generates as CC1156, when i close dialog after process record with automation script custom logic, the systems shows the record with id CC1055 and not the new saved record CC1156, postdata: I use Maximo 7.5.0.9

Comment: Is your question about how to update the visible item in some control after your custom dialog closes?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. The reason Maximo goes to the first record in the table is that it does not know which record to display after opening and closing your new custom dialog and saving the record. 
The simplest solution is to add savemode="ONLOADUNLOAD" in your custom dialog tag in xml.
This will save the record before you open the dialog and Maximo will know to which record to return after closing it.

Comment: This solved my problem, i changed the save mode like you mentioned and it now show the current record :)